# ¿Como muestro datos en RAZOR MVC ASP.NET desde SQL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

Tengo una sentencia SQL :

```
var motivo = conexion.Query("SELECT * FROM historialvisitas WHERE idvisita ='"+rgtro+"' ");
```

Dicha tabla tiene varias columnas, ¿cómo hago para mostrar via RAZOR `@` el valor de una columna en específico?

Ejemplo:

Quiero mostrar los valores de la columna `motivovisita` dentro de un `div`, hago algo como esto: "entre divs"

`<div> @motivo </div>` y `<div> @motivo.motivovisita </div>`

Pero no, da error. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Necesitas convertir los datos de tu consulta retornada (que está dentro de un controlador, supongo) a un modelo y asociar dicho modelo a la vista razor. Revisa esta respuesta, básicamente incluye lo que necesitas implementar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20772447/1732224

Comment: Saludos Atejada, te recomiendo darle una visita a este workshop que hice con el apoyo de la comunidad de donde vengo junto la comunidad de StackOverflow en Español https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY 4 horas de ASPnet MVC espero sea de tu agrado :D

Answer (score 2):

Para escapar el caracter `@` es con otra `@`:

Al generar la consulta de `SQL` tendrás que diseñar un método o un *algo* para que al encontrar una `@` se concatene otra.

Nota: tu consulta dinámica es suceptible a [`SQL Injection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx), no estoy completamente seguro si el método `Query` es personalizado o es parte de una librería, pero deberías seguir las recomendaciones de la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx).